# Opencv3.1, SURf, getting error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run surf code  given on **[this link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html)** with small changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d\nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
    using namespace cv;
    void readme();

    /** @function main */
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {


        Mat img_object = imread("C:\\VC_examples\\IMG_0030.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat img_scene = imread("C:\\VC_examples\\IMG_0031.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data)
        {
            std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
        }

        //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
        int minHessian = 400;
        cv::Ptr<Feature2D> detector = xfeatures2d::SURF::create(minHessian);
        std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

        detector->detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
        detector->detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);

        printf("-- dummy : %f \n", 1.0);
        //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)    
        Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
```

**ERROR LINE:**

```
    **detector->compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);**


    detector->compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using BFMatcher :
    BFMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);



    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
        good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
        std::vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }


    Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, 0);
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, img_object.rows); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, img_object.rows);
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

    //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

/** @function readme */
void readme()
{
    std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_descriptor <img1> <img2>" << std::endl;
}
```

I m getting error

Error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEC3AA996C (opencv_xfeatures2d310.dll) in Example_SURF.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000002B0000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

System info:

```
debug x64
Linker->input:
opencv_videostab310d.lib
opencv_video310d.lib
opencv_ts310d.lib
opencv_superres310d.lib
opencv_stitching310d.lib
opencv_photo310d.lib
opencv_objdetect310d.lib
opencv_ml310d.lib
opencv_imgproc310d.lib
opencv_highgui310d.lib
opencv_flann310d.lib
opencv_features2d310d.lib
opencv_core310d.lib
opencv_calib3d310d.lib
opencv_xobjdetect310d.lib
opencv_xfeatures2d310.lib
opencv_surface_matching310d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs310d.lib
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong version of the library. In your system information I can see that all the libs end with a "d" which is for "Debug" however `opencv_xfeatures2d310.dll` shows a "Release" library. Try changing your build mode or the libs you are using.